# How to inherit parent constants and access them?

Tags: c#, oop, static, constants

How to access the const variable from the parent class?

I have a PI constant and I want to use it in the TCylinder class, how can I access it? I know that I can use Math.PI, but for the future I want to know

```
class TCircle {
const double PI = 3.14;
private double radius;

public double Radius { get => radius; set => radius = value; }


public TCircle(double radius)
{
    this.radius = radius;

}
public virtual double GetArea()
{
    return PI * this.radius * this.radius;
}


class TCylinder : TCircle {

private double height;

public TCylinder(double radius, double height)
    : base(radius)
{
    this.height = height;
}

public override double GetArea()
{
    return (2 * base.GetArea()) + (2 * PI * height);//want to access PI
}
```

}

Comment: Have a look at the `protected` keyword.

Comment: Just make it public or protected. Or better, created a dedicated class to expose your constants.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions, which do *not* use a `T` prefix for classes.

Comment: @vc74: Or use `Math.PI` which already exists :)

Comment: @JonSkeet True, unless the OP really wants Pi's value to be 3.14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Moo-Juice has said, if you give the constant an access modifier other than `private`, it'll be fine.

However, I'd recommend something slightly different: get rid of the constant altogether. It already exists (in a rather more precise form) in `System.Math`. You can use it without any qualification if you add:

```
using static System.Math;
```

at the top of each source file.

As other suggestions:

- I would follow the [.NET naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions), ditching the `T` prefix
- I would use an automatically implemented property instead of a manually implemented property with a separate field:

  ```
  public double Radius { get; set; }
  ```

  Then just use the property everywhere.
- Consider making the types immutable instead. We can't tell whether that's feasible without knowing how you're using them, but it's at least worth considering.
- Consider changing your inheritance model - currently you're saying that it's okay to treat a cylinder as if it's a circle, and I'd expect very few things to *really* work as well with a 3D solid when they're expecting a 2D shape.

Comment: His code would be already much shorter / cleaner with those recommendations. Nothing about expression-bodied methods? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified an access modifier for that property, so it will default to `private`.  Use `protected` instead and classes that inherit it, can see it.